# Custom Post Type, Two categories, Two columns with Pagination

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, pagination, columns

I searching a lot to found a way solves that and no luck at least.

Sorry for my unpulish english, I do my best explaining my issue.

I have a Custom Post Type called `'Events'` this have two categories `'Congresses in Argentina'` and `'International Congresses'`, I need to show the list of posts sorted by columns (2) and with pagination after 5 of each other.
Something like this:

Format: `Cat 1 / Cat 2 [ 1 = most recent / 5 = oldest post ]`

```
 [1] [1]
 [2] [2]
 [3] [3]
 [4] [4]
 [5] [5]
« 1 2 3 »
```

I wondering if I can show the last posts of each category on a row and later the next two ones and so on, this because the design needs to be in this way to show up nicely.

Thanks in advance for your help, any comment would be appreciate it.

Comment: First: If you write examples, please do it in english.

Comment: And **BTW** adding comments doesn't push Qs over here :) So just leave it. Doesn't add value and doesn't help you.

Comment: Kaiser, sorry about that, didn't know, this is my first time here and I read this site for a while looking for some advice, next time I'll keep in mind your words. Awaits patiently for a speed up answer :)

Comment: Take a look at `query_posts` and it's args. Then look how to count with php.

Comment: I use two querys one for each custom term of the custom taxonomy and use a custom pagination than do the job, anyways I'm still looking for a way to show the posts of each category on the same row.

Comment: You can do this in one query using the `tax_query` argument. If it's only about the rows, then this Q is for SO, as it's a plain php Q.

Comment: Right now I use one query with `get_terms()` defining each term on each column for the taxonomy of the post type. Like I really want to do is the row thing, don't understand the way you suggest me, can you show me an example? thanks in advance :)

Comment: As I said: It's a php question. You need `count` your results and then add whatever you need for equal/unequal posts. Already flagged to move over to SO.

Comment: thanks again for your asap answer :) I put on another answer the code I'm using right now to show you, maybe there is an easy way to do what you suggest on that code.

Comment: n/p (even if it was no real answer). And I'm sorry: I don't understand the rest of your comment.

Comment: the follow answer is my actual code, this splits on columns each term found for the taxonomy defined for the post type I create, this great cause it really do what I want, the only thing than escapes for this code is the need to hold each post for each term on the same row, something like the second code I paste on the same answer, this second code I put just to make more clear the result I like to arrive.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the actual code I use to resolve the initial need, this was taken for another question/answer an really works, the only thing I like to make is to put each position of the post of the column at the same row of the other term.

```
<?php
                // for a given post type, return all
                $post_type = 'evento';
                $tax = 'categorias-eventos';
                $tax_terms = get_terms($tax);
                $post_counter = 0; // reset so we can generate columns 
                $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

                    if ($tax_terms) { ?>

                    <ul class="column_wrap" style="width:45%; float:left;">         
                    <?php foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term) {
                         $args = array(
                        'post_type' => $post_type,
                        "$tax" => $tax_term->slug,
                        'post_status' => 'publish',
                        'posts_per_page' => 6,
                      //'posts_per_page' => -1,
                      //'paged' => $paged,
                        'orderby' => 'title',
                        'order' => 'ASC',
                        'caller_get_posts' => 1
                        ); // END $args

                        $my_query = null; // clear the query variable
                        $my_query = new WP_Query($args);

                        if( $my_query->have_posts() ) { ?>

                          <li class="column_row" style="float:left;">
                            <h4><?php echo $tax_term->name; ?></h4>
                          </li>

                            <?php while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
                            <li class="column_row" style="float:left;">
                                <div class="retailer_wrap retailer_id-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                                    <p><strong><?php the_title(); ?></strong></p>
                                    <p><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'eventdate', true);?></p>
                                    <p><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'eventplace', true);?></p>
                                </div>                                  
                            </li>
                            <?php $post_counter++; ?>

                            <?php if ( 0 == $post_counter % 6 ) { ?>
                      </ul>                          
                      <ul class="column_wrap noneed" style="width:45%; float:left;">
                    <?php } // END if $post_counter ?>
                  <?php
                  endwhile;
                  //wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $my_query ) ); 
                } // END if have_posts loop
                wp_reset_query();

              } // END foreach $tax_terms ?>
              </ul>
            <?php } // END if $tax_terms
            ?>
```

This is a graphical example of what I like to make:

```
<div class="term-row">
    <div class="col1"><h4>Term 1</h4></div>
    <div class="col2"><h4>Term 2</h4></div>
</div>
<div class="even-row">
    <div class="col1"> // here begins the 1st post of the 1st term
        <?php the_title(); ?>
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col2"> // here begins the 1st post of the 2nd term
        <?php the_title(); ?>
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="odd-row">
    <div class="col1"> // here begins the 2nd post of the 1st term
        <?php the_title(); ?>
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col2"> // here begins the 2nd post of the 2nd term
        <?php the_title(); ?>
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="even-row">
    <div class="col1"> // here begins the 3rd post of the 1st term
        <?php the_title(); ?>
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col2"> // here begins the 3rd post of the 2nd term
        <?php the_title(); ?>
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="pagination">
    <a href="#">Prev</a>
    <span class="current">1</span>
    <a href="#">2</a>
    <a href="#">Next</a>
</div>
```

Hope its clear enought :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I use to make it work, at least it's a start :)

This was for the first column and first term of custom tax:

```
<ul style="float:left;width:45%;">
<?php $page = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
query_posts("post_type=evento&categorias-eventos=congresos-en-argentina&showposts=3&paged=$page");
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post() ?>
    <li>
        <p><strong><?php the_title(); ?></strong></p>
        <p><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'eventdate', true);?></p>
        <p><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'eventplace', true);?></p>
    </li>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Here begins the second column and second term of the custom tax:

```
<ul style="float:left;width:45%;">
<?php $page = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
query_posts("post_type=evento&categorias-eventos=congresos-internacionales&showposts=3&paged=$page");
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post() ?>                
    <li>
        <p><strong><?php the_title(); ?></strong></p>
        <p><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'eventdate', true);?></p>
        <p><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'eventplace', true);?></p>
    </li>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

And finally the call to a custom pagination function (taken googleing)

```
<?php if ( function_exists('fb_paging_bar') ) fb_paging_bar(); ?>
```